# Firebase index.js

Tags: javascript, firebase

I can't import db to my app.

./src/Feed.js
Attempted import error: 'db' is not exported from './firebase'.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};


const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db=firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth=firebase.auth();


export default {db,auth};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initialiseApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export const auth = firebase.auth();

// You can remove the export default.
```

Comment: i wanna export them so i can use them in another js file with importing

Comment: Yes I understand. I have added the keywords `export` before the declaration. See line 14 and 15.

Comment: i tried that but that didnt worked unfortunately. Auth is fine but db is not getting imported i didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Could you share the code where you import the db?

Comment: i shared the code